# I am having an error while I use flashback

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, flashback

I am having error while I try to use flashback;
I am using oracle SQL

I dropped the table called `fixer`
then I want to get it back , So I use flashback , But I got an error below,

> Error starting at line : 52 in command -
>   Flashback
>   Error report -
>   ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Cheers

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant part of the code.

Comment: The error `ORA-00905: missing keyword` indicates a syntax error in your code. You haven't posted the statement you're running so you'll need to spot it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax to get the table back is :

```
flashback table fixer to before drop;
```

I presume, probably `to` keyword is missing in your statement :

> ```
> flashback table fixer before drop;
> ```
>
> and `ORA-00905` raised due to this.